# Spring boot controller not working and returning resource not found error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I was working on a simple REST API with Spring Boot and have received the error as below.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jan 30 15:10:50 SGT 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No static resource api/v1/courses.
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource api/v1/courses.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I have checked some posts and the common solution is to add `@ComponentScan` but I have ensured that my packages have been in the correct structure for the default component scanning.

This is my Controller.

```java
package dev.shengxue.SpringBootNeo4j.controllers;

import dev.shengxue.SpringBootNeo4j.models.Course;
import dev.shengxue.SpringBootNeo4j.services.CourseService;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/courses")
public class CourseController {
    private final CourseService courseService;

    public CourseController(CourseService courseService) {
        this.courseService = courseService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Course>> courseIndex(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(courseService.getAllCourses(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My Application file.

```java
package dev.shengxue.SpringBootNeo4j;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootNeo4jApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootNeo4jApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And my POM file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dev.shengxue</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootNeo4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootNeo4j</name>
    <description>Tutorial Project for Neo4j</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The build process seems to work just fine

```
2024-01-30T15:09:21.063+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] d.s.S.SpringBootNeo4jApplication         : Starting SpringBootNeo4jApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 24952 (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\IntelliJ Projects\SpringBootNeo4j\target\classes started by DELL in C:\Users\DELL\Documents\IntelliJ Projects\SpringBootNeo4j)
2024-01-30T15:09:21.070+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] d.s.S.SpringBootNeo4jApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-30T15:09:21.178+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-01-30T15:09:21.178+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2024-01-30T15:09:22.364+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Neo4j repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-01-30T15:09:22.604+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 230 ms. Found 0 Neo4j repository interfaces.
2024-01-30T15:09:22.619+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Neo4j repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-01-30T15:09:22.651+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 31 ms. Found 1 Neo4j repository interface.
2024-01-30T15:09:23.732+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-01-30T15:09:23.749+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-01-30T15:09:23.750+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
2024-01-30T15:09:23.833+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-01-30T15:09:23.835+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2655 ms
2024-01-30T15:09:24.396+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] o.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory    : Routing driver instance 1784883759 created for server address ea49c25e.databases.neo4j.io:7687
2024-01-30T15:09:24.612+08:00  WARN 24952 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.c.mapping.Neo4jPersistentEntity  : The entity dev.shengxue.SpringBootNeo4j.models.Course is using a Long value for storing internally generated Neo4j ids. The Neo4j internal Long Ids are deprecated, please consider using an external ID generator.
2024-01-30T15:09:24.656+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2024-01-30T15:09:25.496+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-01-30T15:09:25.515+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [  restartedMain] d.s.S.SpringBootNeo4jApplication         : Started SpringBootNeo4jApplication in 5.097 seconds (process running for 5.752)
2024-01-30T15:09:31.664+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-01-30T15:09:31.664+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-01-30T15:09:31.666+08:00  INFO 24952 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
```

Comment: Is a `CourseController` instance being created?

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting? Judging from the error you are trying `/api/v1/courses` Which doesn't exists whereas `/api/v1/courses/` does. The trailing `/` is needed here as those are different resources.

Comment: for your uri must add / at end of it

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting for resource api/v1/courses, but your mapping is api/v1/courses/.
So you have to replace "/" with "" in get mappng, or get  "api/v1/courses/"